# Variables of integer type in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, variable, arithmetic

There are two ways to define and use variables of integer type in Bash

- `declare -i` a new variable
- use a variable in an arithmetic expression, without declaring it.

My questions:

What are the differences between the variables created by the two ways? Especially differences in their purposes, and when to use which?

Comment: The former is locally scoped, the later is not.

Comment: thanks. can you explain the meaning of "locally scoped", maybe some examples?

Answer (score 7):

The fact the variable is typed gives it some properties a generic variable won't have:

```
f() {
  v=0xff
  echo $v
  v=hello
  echo $v
  v=123a
  echo $v
}

f
declare -i v
f
```

will print

```
0xff
hello
123a

255
0
bash: 123a: value too great for base (error token is "123a")
```

If you are sure your variable will only contain integer values, typing it will give you some flexibility and error checking.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What are the definitions of "untyped" and "typed" variables in general sense for programming languages?  Is an untyped variable defined as a variable whose type can be changed implicitly according to the context? For a typed variable, can we change its type, and if yes, do we have to do it explicitly (like type conversion in C or C++)? (2) Is a "dynamically typed" variable defined as a variable whose type is not changeable implicitly (i.e. the variable is typed), and is determined dynamically at run time?

Comment: These are very broad and sometimes controversial questions. Have a look to http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2010/08/what-to-know-before-debating-type-systems.html and

Comment: Is there something after "and" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818633/does-untyped-mean-the-same-as-dynamically-typing?noredirect=1#comment61224120_36819168

Comment: yes, "sometimes".... I guess I wanted to put another link after the second "and" but changed my mind.